# Apple iPad cannot access IMAP via Dovecot -- SSL unsupported protocol

Tags: ssl, dovecot, imap, apple

I have a mail server that has been running for quite some time. Most of my clients use non-Apple devices or are okay with web-clients. I am only now running into this roadblock, because a new client prefers using the Apple app to read email. They have an older iPad, which maxes out at **iOS 9.3.5**. Just found out this is rather old.

Will my set up run on a more modern iOS?

- When that older iOS device attempts IMAP connection, I am getting the following ***errors***.

  ```
  Jan  8 17:59:40 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x10, ret=1: before SSL initialization
  Jan  8 17:59:40 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: before SSL initialization
  Jan  8 17:59:40 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: before SSL initialization
  Jan  8 17:59:40 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: before SSL initialization
  Jan  8 17:59:40 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL alert: where=0x4008, ret=582: fatal protocol version
  Jan  8 17:59:40 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: error
  Jan  8 17:59:40 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL error: SSL_accept() failed: error:0A000102:SSL routines::unsupported protocol
  Jan  8 17:59:40 host dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected: Connection closed: SSL_accept() failed: error:0A000102:SSL routines::unsupported protocol (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=x.x.x.x, lip=y.y.y.y, TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() failed: error:0A000102:SSL routines::unsupported protocol, session=<7Ag79nIO3MBMFhjy>
  Jan  8 17:59:40 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL error: SSL_accept() syscall failed: Invalid argument
  ```
- With Roundcube and Outlook, here are the log results (similar for both) where ***client IMAP access works***:

  ```
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x10, ret=1: before SSL initialization
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: before SSL initialization
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: before SSL initialization
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: before SSL initialization
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS read client hello
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write server hello
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: TLSv1.3 write encrypted extensions
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write certificate
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: TLSv1.3 write server certificate verify
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write finished
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: TLSv1.3 early data
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: TLSv1.3 early data
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: message repeated 2 times: [ imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: TLSv1.3 early data]
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: TLSv1.3 early data
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS read finished
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x20, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=1: SSL negotiation finished successfully
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<user@domain.net>, method=PLAIN, rip=x.x.x.x, lip=x.x.x.x, mpid=421260, TLS, session=<9gkwPHMOyLNChwcP>
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x10, ret=1: before SSL initialization
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: before SSL initialization
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: before SSL initialization
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: before SSL initialization
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS read client hello
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write server hello
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: TLSv1.3 write encrypted extensions
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write certificate
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: TLSv1.3 write server certificate verify
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write finished
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: TLSv1.3 early data
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: TLSv1.3 early data
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: TLSv1.3 early data
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS read finished
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x20, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=1: SSL negotiation finished successfully
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL alert: close notify
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL alert: close notify
  Jan  8 18:19:14 host dovecot: imap(user@domain.net)<421260><9gkwPHMOyLNChwcP>: Disconnected: Logged out in=316 out=1699 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=1 hdr_bytes=250 body_count=0 body_bytes=0</pre>
  ```

### Here is my setup

- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- Kernel 5.15.0-91-generic
- Dovecot 2.3.16 (7e2e900c1a)
- OpenSSL 3.0.2
- Certbot 2.8.0

##### Config Files

- SSL-configuration

  ```shellsession
  $ cat /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf
  ssl = yes
  verbose_ssl = yes
  ssl_cert = &lt;/etc/letsencrypt/live/host.domain.net/fullchain.pem
  ssl_key = &lt;/etc/letsencrypt/live/host.domain.net/privkey.pem
  ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
  ssl_dh = &lt;/etc/ssl/private/dhparam.pem
  # I've also tried: ssl_min_protocol = TLSv1.3
  ssl_min_protocol = TLSv1.2
  # I've also tried: SSL ciphers to use, the default is:
  #ssl_cipher_list = ALL:!kRSA:!SRP:!kDHd:!DSS:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4:!ADH:!LOW@STRENGTH
  # To disable non-EC DH, use:
  ssl_cipher_list = ALL:!DH:!kRSA:!SRP:!kDHd:!DSS:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4:!ADH:!LOW@STRENGTH</pre>
  ```
- Dovecot:

  ```shellsession
  $ cat /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf
  service imap-login {
    inet_listener imap {
      port = 0
    }
    inet_listener imaps {
      port = 993
      ssl = yes
    }
  }
  service pop3-login {
    inet_listener pop3 {
      port = 0
    }
    inet_listener pop3s {
      port = 995
      ssl = yes
    }
  }
  service lmtp {
    unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
      mode = 0600
      user = postfix
      group = postfix
    }
  }
  service imap {
  }
  service pop3 {
  }
  service auth {
    unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
      mode = 0666
      user = postfix
      group = postfix
    }
    unix_listener auth-userdb {
      mode = 0600
      user = vmail
    }
    user = dovecot
  }
  service auth-worker {
    user = vmail
  }
  service dict {
    unix_listener dict {
    }
  }
  ```

##### SSL Labs Test Results

Overall ***A Rating***. A few highlights from the *Configuration* section.

| Protocols |  |
| --- | --- |
| TLS1.3 | Yes |
| TLS1.2 | Yes |
| TLS1.1 | No |
| TLS1.0 | No |
| SSL 3 | No |
| SSL 2 | No |

| Cipher Suites - TLS 1.3 (server has no preference) |  |
| --- | --- |
| TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x1301) ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) FS | 128 |
| TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x1302) ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) FS | 256 |
| TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0x1303) ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) FS | 256 |

| Cipher Suites - TLS 1.2 (server has no preference) |  |
| --- | --- |
| TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b) ECDH secp521r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA) FS 128 | 128 |
| TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c) ECDH secp521r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA) FS 256 | 256 |
| TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca9) ECDH secp521r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA) FS 256 | 256 |

Comment: Which version of iPadOS? Please *edit your question* and add the information there.

Comment: I just updated the post. Looks like they have an old device. I'm gonna try and find a newer iOS device for testing.

Comment: Yeah, iOS 9.x was originally released in 2015, received its last update in 2019 and is now very definitely out of support. [Wikipedia has a version history overview.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPadOS_version_history) I have one with iOS 12 which is also out of support and slowly becoming less useful as more and more apps get updated and are no longer compatible with iOS 12. No fundamental issues like TLS support yet, though it's probably just a matter of time...